# Better looking menus in gWidget

Tags: r, gwidgets

How can I have better looking menus in gWidget? I found a code in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894097/gwidgets-resize-combobox-to-fit-content)

```
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit="RGtk2")
w <- gwindow()
g <- ggroup(cont=w)
do_expand=TRUE
options <- glayout(cont=g, spacing=5, expand=do_expand)
items <- ""

options[1,1] = "vanilla"
options[1,2] <- gcombobox(items, cont=options)

options[2,1] = "expand"
options[2,2, expand=TRUE] <- gcombobox(items, cont=options)

options[3,1] = "expand, fill"
options[3,2, expand=TRUE, fill="y"] <- gcombobox(items, cont=options)

options[4,1] = "size"
options[4,2] <- (cb <- gcombobox(items, cont=options))
size(cb) <- c(250, -1)

## populate comboboxes 
items <- state.name 
sapply(options[,2], function(i) i[] <- items)
```

that creates a menu like the following:
[image]

And say when you are using one of the dropdown menus it shows something like this:
[image]

However I want to have a flashier look as in the following, any idea how can I create better looking GUI in R (say using gWidgets)?
[image]

Comment: It looks like Quartz. It seems `gWidgets` can only handle RGtk2, qtbase and tcltk.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: What you try to do looks like OSX Quartz. `gWidgets` seems to use only RGtk2, qtbase and tcltk.

Comment: So is there a way to fix it?

Comment: You might want to consider using `Qt` and the [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2011/03/25/#rinside_and_qt) package

Comment: How does `Qt` get connected to `R`?

Comment: Using the RGtk2 backend gives you the possibility of having themes, though you'll have to look at the Gtk docs to figure that out. The `gWdigets2Qt` package on Github might help, though that hasn't been tested in quite awhile.